Trying to save busines post type with meta data
Title:
"Why is get_post_meta() returning false for custom post meta values after using update_post_meta() in WordPress?"
Body:
Hi everyone,
I'm working on a custom REST API endpoint in WordPress that fetches information about a business from a custom post type (business). I'm using update_post_meta() to store some custom data (like phone number, address, social media links, etc.) for a business post. However, when I try to retrieve the stored metadata using get_post_meta(), it keeps returning false.
Here is the code I'm using for the getBusinessInfo function:
public function getBusinessInfo(\WP_REST_Request $request)
{

    $bID = $request->get_param('bID'); // Get the business ID
    
    // Fetch the business post based on the business ID
    $business = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'business',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'p' => $bID,
    ));
    
    if (!$business || empty($business)) {
        return wp_send_json(array(
            'message' => 'error',
            'data' => array(
                'code' => 404,
                'message' => 'Business not found',
            ),
        ));
    }

    // Example hardcoded data to update post meta
    $phone = '+263 123 456 7890';
    $whatsapp = '+263 123 456 7890';
    $email = 'business1@email.com';
    $website = 'https://www.business1.com';
    
    // Update post meta
    update_post_meta($bID, 'phone', $phone);
    update_post_meta($bID, 'whatsApp', $whatsapp);
    update_post_meta($bID, 'email', $email);
    update_post_meta($bID, 'website', $website);

    // Retrieve and log the updated post meta
    $updatedPhone = get_post_meta($bID, 'phone', true);
    $updatedWhatsapp = get_post_meta($bID, 'whatsApp', true);
    $updatedEmail = get_post_meta($bID, 'email', true);
    $updatedWebsite = get_post_meta($bID, 'website', true);

    error_log('Phone: ' . $updatedPhone); // This always returns `false`

    // Return the business info (for example)
    return wp_send_json(array(
        'message' => 'success',
        'data' => array(
            'phone' => $updatedPhone ?: false,
            'whatsApp' => $updatedWhatsapp ?: false,
            'email' => $updatedEmail ?: false,
            'website' => $updatedWebsite ?: false,
        ),
    ));

}

Problem:
After calling update_post_meta(), I am retrieving the values with get_post_meta() but they always return false.
The metadata does not seem to be stored correctly, even though update_post_meta() returns a truthy value.

I just tried your code in a new api endpoint and get_post_meta return the set value. may be you have another plugin that interfere with that.

It's possible there is an object caching system that is not clearing properly/quickly when values are updated. I've experienced this before. Try using a plugin like Query Monitor to investigate and verify the caching system and meta data changes.

You can clear the cache by using clean_post_cache() after updating the post meta and check.
